# stored procedure issue using fields from the #temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a stored procedure that basically does this:

```
Create table #temp(
field1 int,
field2 int,
total int,
total2 int,
total3 int
)
insert into #temp
(
 field1,
 field2,
 )
 Select x.field1, y.field2 from tblA x left join tblB y on x.clientid = y.clientid
```

This works great, this is very much simplified.

Now what I'm doing is UPDATING values for Total, Total2 and Total3 like so:

```
update #temp set Total = field1 + field2  <-- works
                 total2 = field1 + field2 + 300 <-- works
                 total3 = total2 * 100.0    <-- no value
```

So here in the update statement above, if I use the field that had already been inserted into the table, they let me UPDATE it, however, since I updated total2 in the table, I am unable to use it in total3? Any idea why?

Comment: Can u try changing the order? i.e., `total3` and later `total2`

Comment: no because I actually need Total2 to calculate total3. This might not be the best example but in reality I need to set Total2 first and then in total3 I need to use that value

Comment: While updating you can't access the value for Total2 that you want. Maybe think in using  total3 = (field1 + field2 + 300) * 100.0

Comment: @Afonso is right. You are thinking like it was C# or Java or whatever imperative-procedural language. You are using a relational-functional one and you cannot use a variable that way because youa re setting all values at the same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The totals columns are `NULL` at the time you run the update.

So `total3` is doing this: `NULL * 100.0`

You can either update `total3` separately, once you've populated `total2`:

```
update #temp 
set total = field1 + field2,
    total2 = field1 + field2 + 300

update #temp 
set total3 = total2 * 100.0
```

Or you can replace `total2` with the logic that populates it:

```
update #temp 
set total = field1 + field2,
    total2 = field1 + field2 + 300,
    total3 = (field1 + field2 + 300) * 100.0
```

Answer (score 3):

This is your `update`:

```
update #temp
    set Total = field1 + field2  <-- works
        total2 = field1 + field2 + 300 <-- works
        total3 = total2 * 100.0    <-- no value
```

You have only set values for `field1` and `field2`, so the other values are empty.  You need to understand that the `set` clause is executed "all-at-once" not sequentially.  Column references on the left of the `=` are the "new" record; column references on the right are the "old" record.  Hence, you can solve the problem by repeat the expression.

Another way to solve the problem is to use a subquery, CTE, or `apply`:

```
update #temp
    set Total = v.new_total,
        total2 = v2.new_total2 <-- works
        total3 = v2.total2 * 100.0    <-- no value
    from #temp t cross apply
         (values (field1 + field2) ) v(new_total),
         (values (new_total + 300) ) v2(new_total2)
```

Answer (score 2):

May be try the following:

```
update #temp set Total = field1 + field2
                 total2 = field1 + field2 + 300
                 total3 = (field1 + field2 + 300) * 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is because the total2 variable is being set at the same time you are attempting to access it. In order to make the update work correctly you must update total3 with the same logic used to update total2 OR you have to create a separate update for total3.

This is how I would do it:

```
update #temp set Total = field1 + field2  <-- works
                 total2 = field1 + field2 + 300 <-- works
                 total3 = (field1 + field2 + 300) * 100.0    <-- should get value
```

Notice that I put the addition logic for total2 in the paranthesis used to calculate total3. This is because the total2 variable holds no value until the statement completes execution.

The alternative is to split the update into 2 separate statments such as this:

```
 update #temp set Total = field1 + field2  <-- works
                     total2 = field1 + field2 + 300 <-- works
```

and then

```
 update #temp set total3 = (field1 + field2 + 300) * 100.0
```